# Automatically mount volume on EC2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows

There is a procedure given by Amazon to [make a volume available for use](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) that has been attached as a block device. Given that I am attaching an EBS volume that is already ready to be used, is there a way in Windows Server 2008 R2 to either automatically mount or follow the procedure beforehand linked through the commandline rather than the GUI so that it can be automated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use diskpart to do this. Open up cmd.exe and run diskpart. This allows you to execute commands. First, run `san policy=onlineall`. Then, type `list disk`. Because of the nature of EC2, you should consistently be able to mount the same disk. It appears it should be disk 1. Then, type `select disk 1` and `online disk`.

To script this, make a file called diskpart.txt and add these lines:

```
san policy=onlineall
select disk 1
online disk
```

Then you can execute `DISKPART /s diskpart.txt` to automatically mount the drive.

Comment: Is there a way to run in line as a single command, if I am not able to store a text file?

Comment: can't thank you enough :) - please also add to the answer - in DISKPART do `ATTRIBUTE DISK CLEAR READONLY`

Answer (score 1):

You could consider changing the disk policy to "[OnlineAll](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252636.aspx)":

> DISKPART> san policy=OnlineAll

[image]

Comment: I tried running the command, but it did not appear to cause the disk to mount. Here is a screenshot where I first ran the command and then opened disk manager and explorer: http://i.imgur.com/brayXa7.png

Comment: You have to enter diskpart first, then issue the san command.

Comment: Although I now get feedback about the SAN policy changing, it still does not cause the drive to mount: http://i.imgur.com/aM7zJCh.png

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Set-Disk` cmdlet to make the disk online:

```
NAME
    Set-Disk

SYNOPSIS
    Takes a Disk object or unique disk identifiers and a set of attributes, and updates 
    the physical disk on the system.
```

To get a list of all disks:

```
Get-Disk
```

To enable disk #2:

```
Set-Disk -Number 2 -IsOffline $False
```

To enable all offline disks:

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object IsOffline –Eq $True | Set-Disk –IsOffline $False
```

Comment: It seems get-disk and set-disk are not available under Windows Server 2008 R2 (only 2012 and newer include the disk module according to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838967/windows-2008-r2-powershell-the-term-get-disk-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of) )

Comment: Correct. You might need to consider installing PowerShell 4.0 in that case. Or using the workaround proposed in the SO question you link (diskpart script).